# Socket.io / Node.js : cannot run > node server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hello guys i don't know what i did but all was working fine and now i can't run the command

> node server.js

and when i go to the webpage the page is always loading ... i have more detail about the error :

> Unhandled 'error' event
>
> server.js:8:12

but i don't see where is the error ...

i put you my code there :

server.js :

```
var http = require('http');

httpServer = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    console.log('This is a test');
    res.end('Hello World');
});

httpServer.listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServer);


 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('login_chat', function (user) {
        console.log('New user : ', user.username, ' - id : ', user.id);
        io.socket.emit('new_user', user);
    })

});
```

and my client.js :

```
(function($){

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1337');

    startTchat = function(user_id, username) {
        socket.emit('login_chat', {
            id : user_id,
            username : username
        })
    };

    socket.on('error', function(err){
        alert(err);
    });

    socket.on('new_user', function(user){
        alert('New user !');
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: What is the server you are using? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Linux xampp 7.2.6

Comment: i think that my sql service crashed because i can't restart it ... is that possible to be the problem ?

Comment: try `sudo node server.js`

Comment: no ... i can't restart my sql service with this : service mysqld start

Comment: i have this error : Error: 13 (Permission denied) (but all was working fine before)